# T-SQL - Bit Output Parameter Default Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, bit

I'm currently investigating a bug in a stored procedure build over MS SQL Server 2008.
Current stored procedure signature looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.<Name>
(
    ParameterOne int
    , ParameterTwo bit output
)
```

In the code the output parameter value is being evaluated to determine code flows which is at least suspicious to me. Code looks like this:

```
IF ( ParameterTwo = 0 )
BEGIN
      PRINT ParameterTwo
      -- Do stuffs
END

IF ( ParameterTwo = 0)
BEGIN
      PRINT ParameterTwo
      -- Do other stuffs
END
```

On debugging (using PRINTs) I configured flags to be displayed inside the block #1 and block #
2
 but none of them were shown when executed the code. 
However, if you assign a value to ParameterTwo ( ParameterTwo = 0 ) right before the block #1 is executed, the flags are being displayed as expected.

My concern is obviously about bit output parameter creation. When you create a bit parameter (in/out) which is the default value being assigned by MS SQL Server(if any)?. Is that a NULL value? I was under the impression it was a 0 (false) but it does not seems so.

Btw - I'm considering to avoid the output parameter usage withing the code for comparison purposes. Instead, I would tend to think there would be more clear to use internal variable and assign its value to the output parameter before stored procedure ends.

Any responses/comments will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The default value is `NULL`, not `0`.  You should set the value explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) is quite clear on this point:

> Variables are declared in the body of a batch or procedure with the
>   DECLARE statement and are assigned values by using either a SET or
>   SELECT statement. Cursor variables can be declared with this statement
>   and used with other cursor-related statements. After declaration, all
>   variables are initialized as NULL, unless a valu is provided as part
>   of the declaration.

This is also true of columns in tables.  And it applies to bits as well as other types.

Note that a `NULL` value fails all comparisons (except `is null`), so it is not equal to either `0` or `1`.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon! This cleared our my doubt and lead me through a successfull fix for the bug I was looking for. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not default parameters unless you specify a default.  If you do not specify a default, the parameter value is NULL.

For example, the output of all the PRINT statements below is "@bitX is null":

```
create procedure sp_testbit
(
    @bit1 bit,
    @bit2 bit output
)
as begin
    if @bit1 is null print 'sp_testbit @bit1 is null'
    else print 'sp_testbit @bit1 = ' + cast (@bit1 as varchar)

    if @bit2 is null print 'sp_testbit @bit2 is null'
    else print 'sp_testbit @bit2 = ' + cast (@bit2 as varchar)
end
go

declare @bit1 bit, @bit2 bit
exec sp_testbit @bit1, @bit2 output

if @bit1 is null print 'exec sp_testbit @bit1 is null'
else print 'exec sp_testbit @bit1 = ' + cast (@bit1 as varchar)

if @bit2 is null print 'exec sp_testbit @bit2 is null'
else print 'exec sp_testbit @bit2 = ' + cast (@bit2 as varchar)
go

drop procedure sp_testbit
go
```

You can declare a parameter and assign it a default value at the same time.  This makes it optional to pass the input parameters:

```
create procedure sp_testbit
(
    @bit1 bit = 0,
    @bit2 bit = 0 output
)
```

If you don't want the input parameters to be optional, you can explicitly set the values in the stored procedure code:

```
create procedure sp_testbit
(
    @bit1 bit,
    @bit2 bit output
)
as begin
    if @bit1 is null set @bit1 = 0 -- default the input bit
    set @bit2 = 0                  -- default the output bit
```

Comment: Your statements at the end of your post are not correct.  Even SQL 2000 supported optional stored procedure parameters where you can set the value if the parameter is not included.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214375(v=sql.80).aspx  SQL 2008 was the first version where you could declare and set a value on the same line of code.  "Declare @InternalVariable Bit = 0" would work on SQL2008 but fail on earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you.  I was recalling the DECLARE syntax changes.  I'll edit the post.